# How can I check variable annotations?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have annotations from spring,junit jar.How can I check that one annotation is applicable for only class  variable?

Answer (score 6):

Check their javadoc. For example: [`@RunWith`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) has a `@Target(value=TYPE)` annotation, so it's only applicable to types. [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) has a `@Target(value=METHOD)` annotation, so it's only applicable to methods.